# How do I define an array of nested structs in C?

Tags: c

So I currently have 2 structs as seen below where the race_results contains an array of boats participating in the competition. Each race can have one or many boats associated with it.

```
struct boat_data {
    int ID;
    int time_to_complete_hours;
    int time_to_complete_mins;
    int time_to_complete_secs;
} boat_node;

typedef struct race_result {
    char race_date[80];
    int start_time_hours;
    int start_time_mins;
    int start_time_secs;
    int num_boats_competing;
    struct boat_data boat_data[];
} race_node;
```

The issue is that when I later define how many boats there will be in the race (as at this point I'm not sure of how many boats will be in each race) it will not work as it only seems to take one boat and then after that point it exits the nested for loop. **results_array is an array of race_result**

```
fscanf(file, "%d", &total_races);
        for (int races = 0; races < total_races; races++) {
            fscanf(file, " %[^\n]", results_array[races].race_date);
            fscanf(file, " %d", &results_array[races].start_time_hours);
            fscanf(file, " %d", &results_array[races].start_time_mins);
            fscanf(file, " %d", &results_array[races].start_time_secs);
            boat_contenders = fscanf(file, "%d", &results_array[races].num_boats_competing);
            for (int num_boats = 0; num_boats < boat_contenders; num_boats++) {
                scan_status = fscanf(file, "%d\n%d %d %d\n", &results_array[races].boat_data[num_boats].ID,
                                     &results_array[races].boat_data[num_boats].time_to_complete_hours,
                                     &results_array[races].boat_data[num_boats].time_to_complete_mins,
                                     &results_array[races].boat_data[num_boats].time_to_complete_secs);
            }
```

**Edit**

Created an upper bound for the number of boats [10] and also change my nested for loop to use `for (int num_boats = 0; num_boats < results_array[races].num_boats_competing; num_boats++)`

I'm now getting an issue that says that the `results_array` hasn't been initialized ERROR: `-var-create: unable to create variable object`

It is initialized using `struct race_result race_root[total_races];` where `total_races = 6`

Comment: For starters, you're using `boat_contenders` inside your nested for loop but I believe you should instead be using `results_array[races].num_boats_competing` instead. `boat_contenders` stores the return value of the `fscanf` function which returns an integer indicating how many values were successfully read from the file, which is in your example always going to be either `1` or `0`.

Comment: Great thanks for spotting that error!

Comment: Regarding your edit: where is `race_root` declared?

Comment: Sorry the `race_root` is declared in main.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue (the one you are referring to in the question) is here:

```
boat_contenders = fscanf(file, "%d", &results_array[races].num_boats_competing);
```

The return value of `fscanf` is not the value that is read in, but instead the number of values that were successfully read. In this case because your format string specifies only one parameter, assuming a successful read occurs, this value will always be 1. You later use this as the bound for your for loop, which means that it will only run once.

As the bound for your loop you should instead use `results_array[races].num_boats_competing`

This line here is also problematic:

```
struct boat_data boat_data[];
```

Firstly, don't give the variable the same name as the type, even if it compiles it is a bad idea. You also need to specify the size of this array. Think of some sensible upper bound for the number of boats that can be competing in the race. As you also store the actual value of boats competing, it doesn't really matter if this value is larger than the actual number of boats you read in.